# Using my own template beside django rest framework one to upload a file

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I did the upload of an image with some information using a form with Django Rest Framework, it works but displayed using DRF default template, I want to use my own template so that i can add more button and link.
When i looked at that, it's about creating my template "api.html" in a folder rest_framework in my folder of templates but i don't know what i can put in the template content that i want to create.
[image]

My views :

```
class ImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      queryset = Video.objects.all()
      serializer_class = ImageWatermarkSerializer
      filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,filters.OrderingFilter,)
      filter_fields = ('completed',)
      ordering = ('-date_created',)
```

For the serializer :

```
class ImageWatermarkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

      image = serializers.FileField(max_length=None,use_url=True)

      class Meta:
          model = Image
          fields = ('id', 'image_name', 'image_desc', 'date_created', 'image', 'completed', 'size')
```

My models :

```
class Video(models.Model):
      image_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      image_desc = models.TextField(max_length=200)
      completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
      image = models.FileField(upload_to='imgs', default='/home/None/No-image.mp4')
      size = models.IntegerField(default=10)

      def __str__(self):
          return  "%s" % self.image_name
```

In my urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'upl', views.ImageViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^upload/', include(router.urls)), ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already created your api.html file, you need to define template_name in your api view.

```
renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
template_name = 'api.html'
```

And in your `api.html`

```
{% load rest_framework %}

<form class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'upload' %}" method="post" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    # this will include your serializer fields
    {% render_form serializer %}

   # Here you can customize your buttons
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

If you need to change the image field styles DRF gives you style attribute,

```
image = serializers.FileField(
    style={'template': 'app/image.html'}
)
```

Find more details at [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it still displays the old template

Comment: also make sure you defined renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer] in your viewsets

Comment: Yes thank you, i misplaced the template folder but i have this error "'str' object has no attribute 'data'" related to the line {% render_form serializer %}

Comment: ok, in your viewset create get method view and pass the serializer as context.

Comment: I don't see what you mean, can you please do it by editing your answer? Thank you for your help